# Getting null as Acknowledgement from Socket.io

Tags: java, node.js, android-studio, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to realize a client server application with websockets for Android.

The Client Server communication works fine. So i can send and receive messages. But the acknowledgement is null.

The console log from the server:

```
Client connected [id=kTilWFoqr-gj8waEAAAL] with [userid=21]
SOCKET_ID SET
STATUS SET Online for USER '21'
SENT TO CLIENT
null //THIS SHOULD BE hi!
```

On Server side is a socket.io nodejs server like:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const server = new Server();

import * as database from './DBController.js';
import * as dateTime from './DateTime.js';

server.on("connection", async (socket) => {
console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}] with [userid=${socket.handshake.query.userID}]`);
socket.on("MessageClientToServer", async (object) => {  
    const sqlQuery = `insert into messages(...) values(...)`;
    const result = await database.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

    const socketID = await findSocketID(object.incoming_msg_id);
    if(socketID[0].Socket_ID != 'NULL'){
      socket.timeout(500).to(socketID[0].Socket_ID).emit("MessageServerToClient",object,(response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        console.log("SENT TO CLIENT")
    }else{
        console.log("Client OFFLINE");
    }
    
});

// when socket disconnects, remove it from the list:
socket.on("disconnect", async() => {
    console.info(`Client gone [id=${socket.id}]`);
});

server.listen(12123, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:12123');
});
```

The Android Studio Client looks like:

```
public class SocketManager{
    private static SocketManager instance;
    private static Context context;
    MessagesDbAdapter messagesDB = new MessagesDbAdapter(context);;

    private SocketManager() {
    }
    private Socket socket;
    public void connectSocket(String userId) {
        try {
            if(socket==null){
                String serverAddress = "http://ipADDRESS:12123";
                IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
                opts.forceNew = true;
                opts.reconnection = true;
                opts.reconnectionAttempts=5;
                opts.secure = true;
                opts.query = "userID=" + userId;
                socket = IO.socket(serverAddress, opts);

                socket.on("MessageServerToClient", args -> {
                    if(args[0].toString().charAt(0) == '[') {
                        //Response is JSONArray
                    } else if(args[0].toString().charAt(0) == '{') {
                        //Response is JSONObject
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        messagesDB.insertMsg(data);
                    }

                    if (args.length > 1 && args[1] instanceof Ack) {
                        ((Ack) args[1]).call("hi!");
                    }
                });
                socket.connect();
            }else if(!socket.connected()){
                socket.connect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Destroy.
     */
    public void destroy(){
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.off();
            socket.disconnect();
            socket.close();
            socket=null;
        }
    }
}
```